# Validation library or interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, interface

In a typescript REST API project, I saw that it uses interfaces and a validation library at the same time. But I don't really understand the reason behind that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want validation? `interface User { age: number; }` is satisfied with `{age: -47}` but that's not really a valid age.

Comment: so I have to combine interfaces with validation libraries right? interfaces, as I understood, let you know which property you have to insert and their type, so as a template and a half validation, right?

Comment: The interface only provides compile-time type safety. And only for some things. You can specify something is `number` but not "positive integer" or "a number between 1 and 10000 in 0.5 steps" and so on. Even then, if you *receive some payload* you cannot rely on an interface `const user: User = JSON.parse(data)` does not even have the type safety of an interface - `data` can contain arbitrary data, not even matching a user object. There needs to be at least a sanity check before assuming it is assignable to `User`.

Comment: thank you for your response. Now I understand the difference between interfaces and validation libraries. In a nutshell, interfaces are used in development mode to check the inputs of the code, for a safer code in short right? It doesn't allow you to sanity the data, but it gives you a template to follow. It's good to have a more secure structure of your coding flow.

Comment: Correct, interfaces in TS are only exist at compiletime. They are only there to give you at least some guidance when writing the code - e.g., you shouldn't forget this property (because it's not marked optional) or you shouldn't assign numbers to that one (because it's defined as a string) etc. They [do not exist at runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure). During the compilation TS checks if your code passes around the stuff that is expected and if so, it strips out the typings and produces JS code without them.